# Conditionally interpolate values for one data frame based on another lookup table per group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, lookup-tables

This is similar to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520955/how-to-automatically-interpolate-values-for-one-data-frame-based-on-another-look). However, I need to do a few more steps:

•   Group by columns `ID` and `order`

•   For every `val` in `df_dat`, look up the corresponding `ratio` in the `df_lookup` table with the following conditions:

```
o   If val < min(df_lookup$val), set new_ratio = min(df_lookup$ratio)

o   If val > max(df_lookup$val), set new_ratio = max(df_lookup$ratio)

o   If val falls within df_lookup$val range, do a simple linear interpolation
```

My data:

```
library(dplyr)

df_lookup <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~order, ~pct, ~val, ~ratio,
  "batch1", 1, 1,  1, 0.2,
  "batch1", 1, 10, 8, 0.5,
  "batch1", 1, 25, 25, 1.2,
  "batch2", 2, 1, 2, 0.1,
  "batch2", 2, 10, 15, 0.75,
  "batch2", 2, 25, 33, 1.5,
  "batch2", 2, 50, 55, 3.2,
)
df_lookup
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   ID     order   pct   val ratio
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 batch1     1     1     1  0.2 
#> 2 batch1     1    10     8  0.5 
#> 3 batch1     1    25    25  1.2 
#> 4 batch2     2     1     2  0.1 
#> 5 batch2     2    10    15  0.75
#> 6 batch2     2    25    33  1.5 
#> 7 batch2     2    50    55  3.2


df_dat <- tribble(
  ~order, ~ID, ~val,
  1, "batch1", 0.1,
  1, "batch1", 30,
  1, "batch1", 2,
  1, "batch1", 12,
  2, "batch1", 45,
  2, "batch2", 1.5,
  2, "batch2", 30,
  2, "batch2", 13,
  2, "batch2", 60,
)
df_dat
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   order ID       val
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 batch1   0.1
#> 2     1 batch1  30  
#> 3     1 batch1   2  
#> 4     1 batch1  12  
#> 5     2 batch1  45  
#> 6     2 batch2   1.5
#> 7     2 batch2  30  
#> 8     2 batch2  13  
#> 9     2 batch2  60
```

The previous solution did not respect the grouping which generated wrong results.

Example:

For `order = 2` and `ID = batch1`, `new_ratio` should be NA as those conditions aren’t in the lookup table.

For `order = 1`, `ID = batch2` and `val = 30`, `new_ratio` should not be higher than `1.2` (max `ratio` value).

For `order = 1`, `ID = batch1` and `val = 2`, `new_ratio = 0.243` which is the interpolated `ratio` value between 0.2 and 0.5.

Any help appreciated!

```
#error
df_dat %>%
  group_by(ID, order) %>%
  mutate(new_ratio = with(df_lookup, approx(val, ratio, val))$y)
#> Error: Column `new_ratio` must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 7

#wrong output
df_dat %>%
  group_by(ID, order) %>%
  mutate(val1 = val) %>%
  mutate(new_ratio = with(df_lookup, approx(val, ratio, val1))$y)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID, order [3]
#>   order ID       val  val1 new_ratio
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 batch1   0.1   0.1    NA    
#> 2     1 batch1  30    30       1.39 
#> 3     1 batch1   2     2       0.1  
#> 4     1 batch1  12    12       0.643
#> 5     2 batch1  45    45       2.43 
#> 6     2 batch2   1.5   1.5     0.15 
#> 7     2 batch2  30    30       1.39 
#> 8     2 batch2  13    13       0.679
#> 9     2 batch2  60    60      NA
```

Expected output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  order ID       val new_ratio
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 batch1   0.1     0.2  
2     1 batch1  30       1.2  
3     1 batch1   2       0.243
4     1 batch1  12       0.643
5     2 batch1  45      NA    
6     2 batch2   1.5     0.1 
7     2 batch2  30       1.38 
8     2 batch2  13       0.65 
9     2 batch2  60       3.2
```

Comment: Hi Reese. Could you please add your expected output (not just the wrong output). I'm also not entirely clear on your problem statement. Your previous question seems to be quite different. Why do you use `approx` here at all? It doesn't look like you're trying to interpolate anything. Unless I missed something?

Comment: If `val` falls between `val` in lookup table, I need to do linear interpolation `ratio` between the ranges. I added expected output as you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my go at your problem, using `data.table`

I used a lot of in-between steps, so you can check results and operationd each stap, and see what is going on/ So the code can be shortened quite a bit.

```
library(data.table)

#set data to data.tables
setDT(df_dat); setDT(df_lookup)

#set range df_lookup values by ID and order combination
df_lookup[, `:=`( val2   = shift( val, type = "lead" ),
                  ratio2 = shift( ratio, type = "lead" ) ), 
          by = .( ID, order ) ][]

#join non-equi
df_dat[ df_lookup, 
        `:=`( val_start = i.val, 
              val_end = i.val2, 
              ratio_start = i.ratio, 
              ratio_end = i.ratio2 ), 
        on = .( ID, order, val > val, val < val2) ][]


#interpolatie new_ratio for values that fall within a range of dt_lookup
df_dat[, new_ratio := ratio_start + ( (val - val_start) * (ratio_end - ratio_start) / (val_end - val_start) )][]

#create data.table with ratio-value for minimum- and maximum value in df_lookup
df_lookup_min_max <- df_lookup[, .( val_min = min( val ), val_max = max( val ),
                                    ratio_min = min( ratio ), ratio_max = max( ratio ) ), 
                               by = .(ID, order) ]
df_lookup_min_max_melt <- melt( df_lookup_min_max, 
                                id.vars = c( "ID", "order" ),
                                measure.vars = patterns( val = "^val", 
                                                         ratio = "^ratio" ) )

df_dat[ is.na( new_ratio ), 
        new_ratio := df_lookup_min_max_melt[ df_dat[ is.na( new_ratio ), ],
                                             ratio, 
                                             on = .(ID, order, val ),
                                             roll = "nearest" ] ][]

df_dat[, `:=`(val_start = NULL, val_end = NULL, ratio_start = NULL, ratio_end = NULL)][]
```

**final output**

```
#    order     ID  val new_ratio
# 1:     1 batch1  0.1 0.2000000
# 2:     1 batch1 30.0 1.2000000
# 3:     1 batch1  2.0 0.2428571
# 4:     1 batch1 12.0 0.6647059
# 5:     2 batch1 45.0        NA
# 6:     2 batch2  1.5 0.1000000
# 7:     2 batch2 30.0 1.3750000
# 8:     2 batch2 13.0 0.6500000
# 9:     2 batch2 60.0 3.2000000
```

**edit**

the line `5:     2 batch1 45.0        NA` is here because there is no order == 2 & ID == batch1 combination in your df_lookup...
perhaps this is a typo?
Nevertheless: the code seems to hande it just fine ;-)

Comment: can you explain the rolling join portion?

Comment: yes... the join on the intervals is pretty straight forward. The rolling-join part is for joining to the minimum or maximum value. It joins to the nearest value, so if your value < min, it will join to min, if your value > max, it will join to max. Values between min and max could cause problems, but you've already joined these values in the previous step...

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df_dat %>% 
left_join(df_lookup, by=c('ID','order'), suffix = c(".dat", ".lkp")) %>% 
group_by(ID, order, val.dat) %>% 
mutate(ratio_new = case_when(val.dat < min(val.lkp) ~ min(ratio),
                             val.dat > max(val.lkp) ~ max(ratio),
                             #Add ifelse to handle the scenarios where val.lkp and ratio are NAs as approx will fail in these scenarios  
                             between(val.dat, min(val.lkp), max(val.lkp)) ~ ifelse(all(is.na(ratio)), NA_real_, approx(x=val.lkp, y=ratio, xout=val.dat)$y), 
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
slice(1)

# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   ID, order, val.dat [9]
   order ID     val.dat   pct val.lkp ratio ratio_new
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 batch1     0.1     1       1   0.2     0.2  
2     1 batch1     2       1       1   0.2     0.243
3     1 batch1    12       1       1   0.2     0.665
4     1 batch1    30       1       1   0.2     1.2  
5     2 batch1    45      NA      NA  NA      NA    
6     2 batch2     1.5     1       2   0.1     0.1  
7     2 batch2    13       1       2   0.1     0.65 
8     2 batch2    30       1       2   0.1     1.38 
9     2 batch2    60       1       2   0.1     3.2
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we use linear interpolation between `ratio` ranges?

Comment: It does the job now. But when I replace `ifelse` with `if_else`, there was error ``false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 3`. Do you know why?

Comment: Using order=1 and ID=batch1, `approx(x=c(1,8,25), y=c(.2,.5,1.5), xout=c(2,2,2))$y` is the reasoon why we get 3 in the error message, as length of `all(is.na(c(.2,.5,1.2)))` is 1 and length of `approx(...)` is 3. `Ifelse` handlle this case better than `if_else` as from `?ifelse` _ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test ..._ while `if_else` as Hadley said [here](https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2019/vctrs-tools-for-making-size-and-type-consistent-functions) at 13:30 and in many places that its restrict more than needed.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `roll` and `rollends` in `data.table`:

```
df_lookup[, m := (ratio - shift(ratio, -1L)) / (val - shift(val, -1L))]

df_dat[, new_ratio := 
        df_lookup[.SD, on=.(order, ID, val), roll=Inf, rollends=c(FALSE, FALSE), 
            x.m * (i.val - x.val) + x.ratio]
    ]

#for val in df_dat that are more than those in df_lookup
df_dat[is.na(new_ratio), new_ratio := 
    df_lookup[copy(.SD), on=.(order, ID, val), roll=Inf, x.ratio]]

#for val in df_dat that are less than those in df_lookup
df_dat[is.na(new_ratio), new_ratio := 
        df_lookup[copy(.SD), on=.(order, ID, val), roll=-Inf, x.ratio]]
```

output:

```
   order     ID  val new_ratio
1:     1 batch1  0.1 0.2000000
2:     1 batch1 30.0 1.2000000
3:     1 batch1  2.0 0.2428571
4:     1 batch1 12.0 0.6647059
5:     2 batch1 45.0        NA
6:     2 batch2  1.5 0.1000000
7:     2 batch2 30.0 1.3750000
8:     2 batch2 13.0 0.6500000
9:     2 batch2 60.0 3.2000000
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df_lookup <- fread('ID, order, pct, val, ratio
"batch1", 1, 1,  1, 0.2
"batch1", 1, 10, 8, 0.5
"batch1", 1, 25, 25, 1.2
"batch2", 2, 1, 2, 0.1
"batch2", 2, 10, 15, 0.75
"batch2", 2, 25, 33, 1.5
"batch2", 2, 50, 55, 3.2')

df_dat <- fread('order, ID, val
1, "batch1", 0.1
1, "batch1", 30
1, "batch1", 2
1, "batch1", 12
2, "batch1", 45
2, "batch2", 1.5
2, "batch2", 30
2, "batch2", 13
2, "batch2", 60')
```

The last 2 lines of code can also be replaced by a non-equi join:

```
df_dat[is.na(new_ratio), new_ratio:= 
    df_lookup[copy(.SD), on=.(order, ID, val<val), x.ratio, mult="last"]]
df_dat[is.na(new_ratio), new_ratio:= 
    df_lookup[copy(.SD), on=.(order, ID, val>val), x.ratio, mult="first"]]
df_dat
```

Comment: the result didn't match my expected output. Can you check your code again?